# What is causing Flexbox to shrink text in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have recently started learning Flexbox, Grid Layout, and exploring other newer features. Responsive and/or mobile first design is also somewhat new to me, so I wanted to try building something real. So, I started building a small personal website to try it all out. My intent is to use `display: flex;` for my main navigation and then use `display: grid;` in my content area to sort various content "cards."

I am primarily using Chrome's device emulator for testing.

I put together all my markup for my first test page. Then, I began applying styles beginning at the top of the page. I didn't get far before I began styling the navigation, and my first step was to apply `display: flex;` to the `<ul>` that contains my navigation links.

**As soon as `display: flex;` is added, the text inside each `<li>` becomes tiny - so small that I cannot read it on my desktop. I want the text to remain the same size as it was before `display: flex;` is applied** (and have the ability to change it with other styles if necessary).

The original text size is correctly restored if `display: flex;` is removed, but then my navigation is no longer horizontal. Likewise, I am aware that there are other ways to achieve the horizontal navigation I am working on. I specifically chose Flexbox as an educational experience for myself.

I have been experimenting for a few days trying to find a solution. Here is what I have learned:

**The document is correct when...**

1. It is viewed in the latest version of Firefox and Edge.
2. It is viewed in a Chrome window that has been resized manually (instead of using the device emulator).

**The navigation is tiny when...**

1. It is viewed in the latest version of Chrome using the device emulator.
2. It is viewed in the latest version of Chrome on a real Android device. I tested on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

**While testing for a solution, I decided to apply [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to the document to see if a default browser style might be the cause.** Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem, but it creates a different situation (again, in Chrome only) that might be considered a step in the right direction.

**When normalize.css is applied, everything on the page becomes tiny. It's far too small to read, but it's all a consistent size - which is what I want...this size is just too small in Chrome.**

I decided to comment out portions of normalize.css to pin point what was causing the change. I lucked out: it was one of the first declarations: `html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}`. That one rule reduces the size of every element on the page to be tiny, but only in Chrome (and I assume Safari, but I cannot easily test that).

And then it got stranger: removing parts of the HTML will cause the same problem.

**Everything on the page is tiny in Chrome when...**

1. `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;` is applied to `html` or `body`.
2. Some HTML elements are removed. It does not appear to be a certain element. I have encountered the problem after removing `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<ul>`, `<li>`, and `<p>`.

**One less-than-ideal solution is to take advantage of the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` property and increase the size of the text only in the navigation. For example, `#banner li {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 300%;}`.**

There are two downsides to this approach, and both may be solvable if I learn a little more. First, I don't know what percentage I need to accurately resize the text. I used `300%` as a guess, and it looks about right. Second, I do not really understand what the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` property does, so I do not know what other problems using it may cause.

**Here are a few other things I have learned...**

1. I checked the HTML and CSS for errors. Both validate.
2. Changing the font size or units does not make any difference.
3. Changing the height of the `<li>` flex items does not adjust the size of the text; it only changes the height of the box.
4. Flexbox alignment still works properly.
5. I was able to recreate the same problem using a new document.

I created a document to specifically debug this problem. The code is below. My real page is almost identical except that there are more `<section>` tags and content at the bottom. **Removing anything inside the `<section>` tags other than `<header>` tags will cause everything to become tiny.** I have removed almost every element possible. The CSS is shown in a `<style>` tag at the top of the document for simplicity.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flexbox Error Example</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body { font: 100%/1.5 Arial, sans-serif; }

    #banner ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        list-style: none;
        /*-webkit-text-size-adjust: 300%; */
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header id="banner">
    <span>Logo Placeholder</span>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Test1.html">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Test2.html">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="Test3.html">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="Test4.html">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        </header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="List1.html">List 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="List2.html">List 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="List3.html">List 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        </header>
        <ul>
            <li>List 4</li>
            <li>List 5</li>
            <li>List 6</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempor varius erat. Nulla rutrum nisl sit amet massa volutpat lacinia. Ut venenatis cursus mi vel lacinia.</p>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, here is an image that shows the 3 different states of the page:[device emulator screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVJwS.jpg)

I am at a loss on this one. I've tried everything I know to do, spend tons of time researching, and ask some developer friends who could also not tell me what is going on.

Comment: Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: @MrLister Thank you. It looks like I need to research what these meta tags are for, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: You sure know how to post an [mcve]. Nice.